# My cellphone is acting as an RFID tag?

Tags: rfid, cellphone, nfc

I bought a cheap keyboard emulating RFID (miFare) reader for my PC.
I just noticed that the reader can 'read' my cell phone (Pixel 1 XL). Every read seems to return a different serial number.

I can find much stuff online about using a cell phone as an RFID reader, but not much if anything about using it as an RFID tag.

Where can I find more information on this number? Is this a TOTP?

Comment: I think this falls under NFC if you turn that off on your phone it should stop.  but simply googling mifare phone results in plenty of starting information.

Comment: It seems to be called "Host Card Emulation", but I can't find any information on the seemingly random serial numbers my phone returns to my basic RFID reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard NFC implementation on cell phones. The number is effectively a nonce; randomly generated on each scan and made available to apps on the phone via software API. This is sufficient for most use cases: the connection to a user account is made over the internet based on the random nonce. This makes it difficult to track a specific phone, makes replay attacks difficult/impossible, and it makes it impossible to 'spoof' a specific NFC card.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a name for this feature? Can the phone select which nonce/code it sends?

Comment: Generally no. Last time I heard about how this worked, the app either has no control over the code at all, or it can set a very small portion, with the rest randomly generated. It can't pick any arbitrary code, as this could then be used to spoof other tags, which could be an issue for building access control, etc. Now, I don't know where that is enforced - could be in the OS itself or in hardware in the NFC chip.